# Add SVG from URL render black image

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a this [SVG](https://codepen.io/dhavalsisodiya/pen/bvGGvp), which i am trying to load in canvas but it just render the black image, so how to solve it?

version: 2.0.0-beta.7

I have tried both method loadSVGFromString as well as loadSVGFromURL but no success:

```
//Using loadSVGFromString
var a = 'svg string';
fabric.loadSVGFromString(a,function(objects, options) {
  var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});

//using loadSVGFromURL
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('URL Here', function(objects,options) {
    var group = new fabric.Group(objects, {
        left: 50,
        top: 50,
    });
    canvas.add(group);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

checkout this [codepen](https://codepen.io/dhavalsisodiya/pen/wmvBvg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"All black" svgs often is a result of some invalid or unsupported svg markup.
In your case I think you should remove the `fill-opacity="null"` references from your svg.

Comment: Yup, thanks a lot. Where do i found which references are invalid in my svg?

Comment: I dont know of any tools, I just looked at your svg and thought it looked off with a opacity value of null. Then I verified this attribute must be a number on mozilla (you can click on the <opacity-value>) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-opacity. I would think the same goes for your stroke-opacity="null" btw, trying searching for stroke-opacity on the same site. 

But are you creating these svg yourself or are you exporting them from a program? Often you can fix these kind of problems when exporting a svg from a vector tool.

Comment: thanks for the detail, i am creating svg using third party websites.

Comment: I see. If you want a free svg generator with good svg export possibilities for web then i would recommend InkScape, or you could check out GravitDesigner if that's not what you already are using. If you are willing to pay a little more i would recommend Affinity Designer (my personal favorite). Or if you would like a event better but way way more expensive alternative you could buy Adobe Illustrator. GL :)